# How to find androidx.browser:browser version?

Tags: android, androidx, android-customtabs

I want to use `CustomTabsIntent`. But I don't find androidx's customTabs path and version.

Finally I got this: `androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0`

I want to know the right steps.

I saw this, but I don't find path and version.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/package-summary

My steps:

- Add `com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0`
- `Refactor` -> `Migrate to AndroidX` in Android Studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full listing of old support packages and new ones is available here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 2):

There is a page now with the latest [AndroidX versions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions). You can look up the artifact group and id if you go to the release notes page by clicking on the artifact version.